# How to pass Variable value from Azure Devops to POM.xml

Tags: selenium, maven, automation, azure-devops, pom.xml

I have one POM.xml file in which i want to pass TestNG.XML value on run time using azure devops pipeline in surefire under plugin tag

Kindly help to acheieve this.

Answer (score 0):

> How to pass Variable value from Azure Devops to POM.xml

You could use the [Replace Token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) pass variable value to POM.xml.

[image]

The format of variable in `POM.xml` file is `#{TheVariable}#`

Then, define the key's values on the Variables:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Pipeline's Maven task provides a different way of passing the parameters. - `Dmaven.test.skip=true` or `-DskipTests=true` or `-D<var-name>=<value>` can be passed through `options` argument of `Maven` task.
So you may use a variable like `test.filename` and assign it required value in a way something like this -

```
steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: './pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'package'
    options: 'package -Dtest.filename=TestNG.xml'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have implemented the solution to read Azure CI variables in pom.xml. Below are the steps 

**step1**: pom.xml entry
  Define properties in pom.xml. Idea is to provide dynamic value to var.testFileName from CI pipeline. 

   <properties> 
     <fileName>{var.testFileName}</fileName>
   </properties>

**step2**: 
  Define Azure CI variable or Azure pipeline Library VariableGroup 
  Lets use Library as a centralized place to host all such values.

      variableGroup: variableGroup1
      variables:  
         name: test.filename
         value: TestNG.xml

**step3**: azure-pipelines.yml 
  Reference variable in your azure-pipelines.yml
 
   variables:
     - group: variableGroup1
     - name: testFileName
      value: '$(test.filename)' 

Now define task in yaml, which will replace the text in pom.xml

 - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Replace text'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
       script: |
         sed -i 's/{var.testFileName}/$(testFileName)/g' pom.xml
```